# How do I get past a wrong "your question seems to contain code that isn't formatted" error?

Tags: support, code-formatting, error-message

The post looks fine in the preview window. Why can't I override the smartallec parser and post my question?

I don't know any better way to format the Boost error messages. I have tried indented 4 chars, and with >, and the best way seems to just use a `<pre>` tag to preserve the formatting. It might be possible to get around the annoying parser warning by putting 4 spaces and a line break before each line of the lengthy error messages, but I'm not about to do that just to see if it works. Argh. Why is there no way to override the warning? Or is there?

(I finally managed to post the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29052443/correct-syntax-to-assign-unique-ptr-to-new-boostasioio-servicework-object), and it was the Boost error messages that were getting detected as seeming code. I only got it to work by using the code snippet tool, but it makes them show up as run-able code snippets, which is far worse than if it just accepted by `<pre>` tags.)

Edit: Ok, the Code Sample button *does* work on such a blog. I tried that before, but it seemed to collapse the indentation into a blob.

Comment: Could it be that there is no other code in your question apart from these Boost error messages?

Comment: There's a bunch, but I think I have hit it all with either 4-space indent, or the 'code' button. I am now trying using the code snippet tool, but it seems to assume I'm doing a run-able code snippet. I am sure I am not the only one who has considered abandoning contributing because of this roadblocking warning.

Comment: Interesting. You were able to post it, yes, but the error message to actual code ratio is pretty high there, so it probably explains why the algorithm resulted in a false positive. Or did it?

Comment: Well, it seems to me that error messages will tend to include code in them, so there should be a fairly easy way to post them correctly without having this error message deny posting the question. How is someone supposed to post a question with error messages with code in them, preserving the formatting? The way I found worked, but added silly "run the code snippet" buttons, which is far worse than just letting me post them in a <pre> tag, which looked fine.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you *can* just use the Code Sample button and get it to format properly. I had tried that, but it seemed to mess up the indentation. I guess it can work, after all.

Example:

```
g++ -std=c++0x -c -Wall ../comms/CommServer.cpp
../comms/CommServer.cpp: In member function ‘void CommServer::Listen()’:
../comms/CommServer.cpp:39:13: error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::unique_ptr<boost::asio::io_service::work>’ and ‘boost::asio::io_service::work*’)
   KeepAlive = new boost::asio::io_service::work(IO_Service);
             ^
../comms/CommServer.cpp:39:13: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/memory:81:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/config/no_tr1/memory.hpp:21,
                 from /usr/include/boost/get_pointer.hpp:14,
                 from /usr/include/boost/bind/mem_fn.hpp:25,
                 from /usr/include/boost/mem_fn.hpp:22,
                 from /usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:26,
                 from /usr/include/boost/bind.hpp:22,
                 from ../comms/Comms.h:16,
                 from ../comms/CommServer.h:16,
                 from ../comms/CommServer.cpp:10:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/unique_ptr.h:190:7: note: std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>& std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::operator=(std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&&) [with _Tp = boost::asio::io_service::work; _Dp = std::default_delete<boost::asio::io_service::work>]
       operator=(unique_ptr&& __u) noexcept
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/unique_ptr.h:190:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘boost::asio::io_service::work*’ to ‘std::unique_ptr<boost::asio::io_service::work>&&’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/unique_ptr.h:203:2: note: template<class _Up, class _Ep> typename std::enable_if<std::__and_<std::is_convertible<typename std::unique_ptr<_Up, _Ep>::pointer, typename std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::_Pointer::type>, std::__not_<std::is_array<_Up> > >::value, std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&>::type std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::operator=(std::unique_ptr<_Up, _Ep>&&) [with _Up = _Up; _Ep = _Ep; _Tp = boost::asio::io_service::work; _Dp = std::default_delete<boost::asio::io_service::work>]
  operator=(unique_ptr<_Up, _Ep>&& __u) noexcept
  ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/unique_ptr.h:203:2: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
../comms/CommServer.cpp:39:13: note:   mismatched types ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>’ and ‘boost::asio::io_service::work*’
   KeepAlive = new boost::asio::io_service::work(IO_Service);
             ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/memory:81:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/config/no_tr1/memory.hpp:21,
                 from /usr/include/boost/get_pointer.hpp:14,
                 from /usr/include/boost/bind/mem_fn.hpp:25,
                 from /usr/include/boost/mem_fn.hpp:22,
                 from /usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:26,
                 from /usr/include/boost/bind.hpp:22,
                 from ../comms/Comms.h:16,
                 from ../comms/CommServer.h:16,
                 from ../comms/CommServer.cpp:10:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/unique_ptr.h:211:7: note: std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>& std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::operator=(std::nullptr_t) [with _Tp = boost::asio::io_service::work; _Dp = std::default_delete<boost::asio::io_service::work>; std::nullptr_t = std::nullptr_t]
       operator=(nullptr_t) noexcept
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/unique_ptr.h:211:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘boost::asio::io_service::work*’ to ‘std::nullptr_t’
```